# FOS user manager deprecated?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I get this error in prod mode (not in dev mode actually):

```
 Deprecated: Using the UserManager as user provider is deprecated.
```

For this line:

```
            // Get the user from the database
            $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->loadUserByUsername($username);
```

It says to use `FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider` but how do I use `loadUserByUsername` on the UserProvider object?

Thanks

Comment: Use provider instead of manager. $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_provider')->loadUserByUsername($username);

Comment: I get this error: `You have requested a non-existent service &quot;fos_user.user_provider&quot;...`

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md#securitybundle-integration)

> Although the built-in user managers also implement
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface using the
>   UserManager as user provider is deprecated and will trigger an error.
>   Use 'FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider' instead.